# OCaml - functors - how to use?

Tags: ocaml, functor

Is someone may explain me functors. I would like to simple examples. When we should use functors?

Comment: You can see this [tutorial on ocaml.org](http://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/modules.html) and [Chapter 9 of Real World OCaml](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/functors.html).

Comment: Simply say, functors are like `interface` in Java.

Comment: @JacksonTale, er, no. The closest thing to Java interfaces are module types, and even those are substantially different. The closest thing to a functor would be a generic class.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg Sorry, you are right.

Answer (score 4):

Functors, essentially are a way to write modules in terms of other modules.

A pretty classic example is the [`Map.Make`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Map.Make.html) functor from the standard library. This functor lets you define a map with a specific key type.

Here's a trivial and rather dumb example:

```
module Color = struct
    type t = Red | Yellow | Blue | Green | White | Black

    let compare a b =
        let int_of_color = function
            | Red -> 0
            | Yellow -> 1
            | Blue -> 2
            | Green -> 3
            | White -> 4
            | Black -> 5 in
        compare (int_of_color a) (int_of_color b)
end

module ColorMap = Map.Make(Color)
```

Loading this in `ocaml` shows the signature of the generated modules:

```
module Color :
  sig
    type t = Red | Yellow | Blue | Green | White | Black
    val compare : t -> t -> int
  end
module ColorMap :
  sig
    type key = Color.t
    type 'a t = 'a Map.Make(Color).t
    val empty : 'a t
    val is_empty : 'a t -> bool
    val mem : key -> 'a t -> bool
    val add : key -> 'a -> 'a t -> 'a t
    val singleton : key -> 'a -> 'a t
    val remove : key -> 'a t -> 'a t
    val merge :
      (key -> 'a option -> 'b option -> 'c option) -> 'a t -> 'b t -> 'c t
    val compare : ('a -> 'a -> int) -> 'a t -> 'a t -> int
    val equal : ('a -> 'a -> bool) -> 'a t -> 'a t -> bool
    val iter : (key -> 'a -> unit) -> 'a t -> unit
    val fold : (key -> 'a -> 'b -> 'b) -> 'a t -> 'b -> 'b
    val for_all : (key -> 'a -> bool) -> 'a t -> bool
    val exists : (key -> 'a -> bool) -> 'a t -> bool
    val filter : (key -> 'a -> bool) -> 'a t -> 'a t
    val partition : (key -> 'a -> bool) -> 'a t -> 'a t * 'a t
    val cardinal : 'a t -> int
    val bindings : 'a t -> (key * 'a) list
    val min_binding : 'a t -> key * 'a
    val max_binding : 'a t -> key * 'a
    val choose : 'a t -> key * 'a
    val split : key -> 'a t -> 'a t * 'a option * 'a t
    val find : key -> 'a t -> 'a
    val map : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a t -> 'b t
    val mapi : (key -> 'a -> 'b) -> 'a t -> 'b t
  end
```

The simple `module ColorMap = Map.Make(Color)` has created a module that implements a map where the keys are colors. It's now possible to call `ColorMap.singleton Color.Red 1` and get a map of red to the number 1.

Note that the use of `Map.Make` worked because the passed module (`Color`) satisfies the requirements of the `Map.Make` functor. The docs say the type of the functor is `module Make: functor (Ord : OrderedType) -> S with type key = Ord.t`. The `: OrderedType` means that the input module (`Color`) has to be consistent (I'm sure there's a more official term) with the [`OrderedType`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Map.OrderedType.html) module signature.

To be consistent with `OrderedType` the input module has to have a type `t` and a function `compare` with signature `t -> t -> int`. In other words there has to be a way to compare values of type `t`. If you look at the types reported by `ocaml` that's exactly what `Color` supplies.

When to use functors is a much more difficult question as often there are several possible designs each with their own trade-offs. But most of the time you'll use functors when a library supplies them as the recommended way of doing something.